# how can I do facebook login using FB.api

Tags: node.js, facebook

```js
var FB = require('fb'),
    fb = new FB.Facebook(options); 
    var options = FB.options();
var {Facebook, FacebookApiException} = require('fb'),
    fb = new Facebook(options);
    
FB.api('me/feed', 'post', { fields: ['email', 'name']}, function (req, res) {
//FB.setAccessToken(req.query.fb_token);
  if(!res || res.error) {
    console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Post Id: ' + res.id);
});
```

How can I get user email and name by passing access token as a query parameter.

Comment: By removing `/feed` maybe? That’s a list of posts, and posts don’t have email addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but according to the docs on npm:

```
FB.setAccessToken(req.query.fb_token);
FB.api('me', {fields: ['email', 'name'], (req, res) => {
  if(!res || res.error) {
    console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
    return;
  }
  console.log(res.email, res.name);
});
```

Make sure you know when to use GET and POST, and of course the feed endpoint does not return any email. You just copied that code from the docs, but from the wrong place ;)

Comment: `function facebook(req,res,next) {
    var token = req.query.fb_token;
    
    console.log(token);
    FB.api('me', { fields: ['email', 'name'], access_token: token }, function(req, res) {
        FB.setAccessToken(token);
        if (!res || res.error) {
            console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
            return;
        }
        console.log(res.email, res.name);
    });
}
router.post('/fb',facebook);
`

Comment: I made these changes, but I am not getting output.

Comment: please be more specific and do some debugging. how about "console.log(res)" at the beginning of the callback, for example? did you debug the access token too?

Comment: side note: node.js supports a lot of ES6 features since many versions, you should consider using them. arrow functions and const/let, for example. don´t program old code.